# Proof that $\frac{3^{a}-3^{a-2}}{3^{a-1}+3^{a}}=\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that:

$$\frac{3^{a}-3^{a-2}}{3^{a-1}+3^{a}}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: What have you done so far? Or where exactly are you having difficulties?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Product_of_Powers) $x^{m+n}=x^m\cdot x^n,$

$$3^a-3^{a-2}=3^{a-2}(3^2-1)$$

and $$3^{a-1}+3^a=3^{a-1}(1+3)$$

Answer (score 4):

Simplify by $3^a$:$$\frac{3^{a}-3^{a-2}}{3^{a-1}+3^{a}}=\frac{3^0-3^{-2}}{3^{-1}+3^0}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Or equivalently, by $3^{a-2}$:$$\frac{3^{a}-3^{a-2}}{3^{a-1}+3^{a}}=\frac{3^2-3^0}{3^{1}+3^2}=\frac{2}{3}.$$